# Minimax algorithm's recursion does not return what is expected to - Python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, minimax

(Sorry for all the errors I can make: I'm new around here and english is not my first language.)

I'm trying to program an interactive connect 4 in Python using the minimax algorithm (alpha beta pruning will be added later). Thing is: when the algorithm reaches the base case it continues to evaluate for some more iterations (instead of just going back) and at some point (generally after three or four more iterations) it doesn't return the vector it is suppose to: it just returns a number and so Python launches a

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

when it compares to best or worst. I have been stuck here for quite a long time and I just dont know why the error happens.

This is my code so far:

```
def minimax (board,depth,maximizingPlayer,token,node=-1) :

    # Base case
    if (depth==0) or (not successor(board)) or (winner(board,token)) :
        return [node,evaluation(board)]

    if maximizingPlayer:
        best = -math.inf
        for son in succesor(board) :
            place(board,son,token)
            [n,v] = minimax(board,depth-1,False,'O',son)
            remove(board,son,token)
            if v>best :
                move,best = n,v
        return move

    else : # minimizingPlayer
        worst = math.inf
        for son in succesor(board) :
            place(board,son,token)
            [n,v] = minimax(board,depth-1,False,'O',son)
            remove(board,son,token)
            if v<worst :
                move,worst = n,v
        return move
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you're returning `move` in 2 cases, when you ought to return `node, value` (probably `move, best`) as a tuple.

Comment: BTW just use `return node, evaluation(board)`; and `n, v = minimax(....)`, no need to use lists.

Comment: Thank you, @BlackBear, everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: Thank you to you too, @Antti Haapala